# edit by id is not working in Angular although the route that is getting passed is correct

Tags: node.js, angular, routes

I want to edit and show value in form when user is editing but its not working. Angular frontend is capturing the correct route but data is not getting fetched from backend and no api is getting called. The content is not shown on browser. I'm attatching the git repository link also in case if you want to take a look https://github.com/tridibc2/blog-admin-mean. The route to do the editing is **http://localhost:4200/admin/blog** and click on edit button. Below I'm attaching **edit-blog.component.html** code

```
    <h3>Edit this blog</h3>
    <div class="row" style="text-align:left">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form #createBlogForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editThisBlog()">

          <div class="form-group">


            <label>Blog Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="blogTitle" [(ngModel)]="currentBlog.title" #title="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter blog Title"
              required>

          </div>
          <div [hidden]="title.valid || title.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
           Blog Title is required 
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="blogDescription" [(ngModel)]="currentBlog.description" #description="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description"
              required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter the blog body</label>
            <textarea name="blogBodyHtml" [(ngModel)]="currentBlog.bodyHtml" #bodyHtml="ngModel" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select [(ngModel)]="currentBlog.category" #category="ngModel" name="blogCategory" class="form-control" id="category" required>
                  <option *ngFor="let category of possibleCategories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
                </select>
          </div>


          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!createBlogForm.form.valid">Edit the blog</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**edit-blog.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogpostService } from 'src/app/client/blogpost.service';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng6-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-blog',
  templateUrl: './edit-blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-blog.component.css']
})
export class EditBlogComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentBlog;
  public possibleCategories = ["Comedy", "Action", "Drama", "Technology","Cooking","Travel"];

  constructor(private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public toastr: ToastsManager) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log("blogedit ngOnInIt called");
    let myBlogId = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogId');
    console.log(myBlogId);
     this.blogpostService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe(

                data =>{
                  console.log(data);
                  this.currentBlog = data;
                  console.log(this.currentBlog);
                  },

                error =>{
                  console.log("some error occured");
                  console.log(error.errorMessage);

                })
  }

  public editThisBlog(): any {
    this.blogpostService.editBlog(this.currentBlog.blogId, this.currentBlog).subscribe(

      data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.toastr.success('Blog Edited Successfully.', 'Success!');
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.router.navigate(['/blog', this.currentBlog.blogId]);
        }, 1000)
      },
      error =>{
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
        this.toastr.error('Some Error Occured.', 'Oops!');
      }
    )

  }

}
```

**service code**

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpBackend, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogpostService {

  public allBlogs;
  public currentBlog;
  errorData: {};
  isLoggedIn = false;

  public baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/blogs';


  constructor(private _http:HttpClient, private handler: HttpBackend) { }

  public getAllBlogs(): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/all').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;
   }

   public getSingleBlogInformation(currentBlogId): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/view/' + currentBlogId).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
    return myResponse;
  }

  public createBlog(blogData): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/create', blogData);
    return myResponse;

  }

  public deleteBlog(blogId): any {
    let data = {}
    let myResponse = this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/' + blogId + '/delete', blogId);
    return myResponse;

  }

  public editBlog(blogId, blogData): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.put(this.baseUrl + '/edit' + '/' + blogId, blogData);
    return myResponse;
  }

  public getUserInfoFromLocalStorage: any = () =>{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
  }

  public setUserInfoInLocalStorage: any = (data) =>{
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  public signinFunction(data): Observable<any>{

    const params = new HttpParams()

    .set('email', data.email)
    .set('password', data.password)


    return this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, params);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }

}
```

node controller code for the edit api

```
    BlogModel.findOne({ 'blogId': req.params.blogId }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err)
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            console.log('No Blog Found')
            res.send("No Blog Found")
        } else {

            result.views += 1;
            result.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send(err)
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Blog updated successfully")
                    res.send(result)

                }
            });// end result

        }
    });
}
```

route

```
app.put(baseUrl+'/edit/:blogId',blogController.editBlog);
```

the data object is like this

```
{"title":"Blog Title 2 Custom","description":"Blog description 2 Custom","bodyHtml":"<h3>Heading of the body CUSTOM</h3><p>This is the first blog data getting uploaded n blog project</p>","views":5,"isPublished":true,"category":"tech","author":"Decardo","tags":["english movies, action movies, comedy"],"_id":"5e1120d223416207d8ae5e1b","blogId":"nbfO8hJp","created":"2020-01-04T23:33:38.000Z","lastModified":"2020-01-04T23:33:38.000Z","__v":0}
```

Comment: try to console.log

Comment: nothing is coming on console

Comment: try to make a path of `console.log` that will follow all of the methods that should be hit when this function is executed. is there nothing being logged for node controller code for the edit api?

Comment: nothing is coming. I think it is not able to hit the api

Answer (score 1):

Just fix the path of edit button like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/edit', blog.blogId]" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

Forward on the API part your edit method is incomplete as you are not updating the object that you find with the new values.

```
let editBlog = (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    BlogModel.findOne({ 'blogId': req.params.blogId }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err)
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            console.log('No Blog Found')
            res.send("No Blog Found")
        } else {
          for (let key in data) {
            result[key] = data[key];
          }
          result.views += 1;
            result.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send(err)
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Blog updated successfully")
                    res.send(result)
                }
            });// end result
        }
    });
};
```

To edit the Blog's info you are calling editBlog method from blogpost service passing into it an id (blogId) and a body (blogData). So on the server side what you get is an id and body which is the update data. You can get the body from request so req.body. What you missed is to update actually the object you found, and that's why i made a loop to update the values of Blog object with the new values from req.body, and only once updated you save it. Obviously there are other ways to update the object we want to modify.

Comment: this works perfectly! can you explain me more about this part that you added under controller? 
      else {
          for (let key in data) {
            result[key] = data[key];
          }
Also I need every other route to be the children of admin component since I'm routing the remaining components to load
inside the admin component.

Comment: Oh, i just figured out now that you needed all components as children. I'll update my answer then! Make sure to revert your changes on admin-routing module and for the "add post" button, because you did well if you want to keep all children under admin.